# What is the latest .NET Framework that works with WCF RIA Services and EF 5.0 in a Silverlight 5 LOB application?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I am currently upgrading our company's Line of Business Application (some of you remember the buzz about Silverlight in 2009 at PDC in Los Angeles, right?) and I would like to know (if anybody knows) where the supported Microsoft versions of the following end:

VS2013 (how about VS2015?)
MVVM Light
Silverlight 5
Silverlight 5 Toolkit
Entity Framework 5.0
.NET Framework 4.5.1 (will it work on the Microsoft mandated .NET Framework 4.5.2?)

Are we stuck using VS2012? So far I can build and run in VS2013, but have received occasional exceptions. I'm just getting wound up with this upgrade, so I'll be glad to supply any exceptions that occur. One of them may actually be environment related.

My main focus of the question is to hear somebody [reliable] from the dev community say: "Yes, EF 5.0 (Version 4.4.0.0 in web.config?) works just fine with the latest WCF RIA Services Toolkit (from way back in 2011, I believe) but you have to do thus and so in VS2013 (and VS2015) to ensure you don't corrupt your data... or give yourself an ulcer..."

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, not [reliable] enough to give my opinion. ask ms maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Silverlight 5 with RIA Services and Entity Framework 6 in one project. You need the package "RIA Services for EntityFramework 6+" (RIAServicesContrib.EntityFramework) on NuGet for a compatible `DbDomainService<T>`.

I used to use the same project with EntityFramework 5 too. For that, you need the "RIA Services for EntityFramework Code-First (DbContext)" (RIAServices.EntityFramework) NuGet package.

I'm using VS2013 and have no issues.

I had once installed the VS2015 preview and saw that Silverlight is still a project template and it would suprise me if there was an issue.

I doubt that your exceptions are due to some incompatibility issues with newer Visual Studios or Entity Frameworks.

Note also that RIA Servies has been open-sourced and is thus likely to outlive Silverlight itself.